# Is it possible to program an Arduino from an Android device?

Tags: android, gcc, arduino

Is it possible to write Arduino programs on Android phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it seems like it is possible. What you need is AVR-GCC to compile your code, and it looks like [someone has ported](http://code.google.com/p/andavr/) it to [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29).

But how you would go about getting the program onto your Arduino device I'll guess is quite a bit harder though.

You'll probably want to check out the forum post *[Android Hosted Toolchain](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=122043&start=20)*.

Comment: nice! Just as an FYI, I am trying to build a Scratch-like app for android that can be used to program arduino's. That way even my 5-year-old niece can build robots.

Comment: @HansStam that sound really cool! :D

Comment: not nearly as cool as your awesome hat

Comment: You can remotely program an Arduino using Xbee. I've never done it but it's definitely a way you could get this done.

Comment: thanks +sbonkosky, I would prefer to do it via bluetooth as most android phones come with bluetooth. I am going to try to use this: http://letsmakerobots.com/node/30915